# Html 5 canvas rotating a ruler in both the direction when origin is shifted

Tags: jquery-ui, html5-canvas

Can anyone tell me how to rotate the ruler (scale), in canvas? In both the directions (clockwise and anti) I am able to rotate the ruler in clockwise but not anticlockwise. The problem comes If I shift the origin to ruler (left,top). Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: Use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to give us an example of your problem.

Comment: Please see this jsfiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/mayanknimje87/8Qk9t/3/         
 As you can see ruler is dragging from 0-2 and can rotate from rest part,  i want to make it rotatable in both the direction. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the ruler CCW from a horizontal position , you need to move the mouse above or to the left of the center of the rotation; because the center is at the upper left corner, that means you have to move your mouse off of the ruler.  The problem is that the `mousemove` handler that rotates the ruler only works when the mouse is over the ruler.  You can fix this by attaching that same handler to the parent container.

I got your code to work by replacing the line

```
$('#id_scale').bind("mousemove",function(e){
```

with

```
$('#parent_container').bind("mousemove",function(e){
```

## [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Qk9t/4/) (rotation only works in Firefox, as does the original)

You might consider adding other transform styles so that your code will work in browsers other than Firefox.

Comment: Very very thanks to you ellisbben. This is a great help to me. Can you give me one more favor, as you can check when i put pencil over the scale it draws the line. But when i rotate it, it won't draw. Can you give me some suggestions or help. Thanks for your great help.